# MYSQL: Select the Max Values in VARCHAR Field from two different tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I am newbie to MYSQL.There are two tables namely table A and table B.Just need the Max values from two different tables.
**Expected Output:**

```
AG/2016-17/P/046
```

```
  table_A                                 
       In_No
     AG/2016-17/P/01
     AG/2016-17/P/029
     AG/2016-17/P/030

     table_B
      In_No
 AG/2016-17/P/01
 AG/2016-17/P/046
 AG/2016-17/P/015
```

**SQL:**

```
select MAX(bv) from(
SELECT MAX(CAST(SUBSTRING(In_No, 14, length(In_No)-3) bv AS UNSIGNED)) FROM table_A
union all
SELECT MAX(CAST(SUBSTRING(In_No, 14, length(In_No)-3) bv AS UNSIGNED)) FROM table_B) as a
```

Something is wrong.It is not showing the proper output.Please suggest me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the output you get?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT In_No, substring_index(In_No, '/', 2) AS In_No_sub
FROM (
    SELECT In_No FROM table_A
    UNION ALL
    SELECT In_No FROM table_B
) t
ORDER BY substring_index(In_No, '/', -1) + 0 DESC
LIMIT 1
```

#### SQLFiddle Demo

Comment: Thanks for Query.But In my case it is just showing this  'AG/2016-17', not showing the AG/2016/P/046.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks for your correcting. Updated it, please review.

Comment: @10086 Still it is showing the same output i.e 'AG/2016-17'. In demo also, it it showing the same output.

Comment: My first answer has given you `AG/2016-17/P/046`. Updated again, please check. @user007

Comment: @10086 I have no idea. I am not getting the Output it showing the In_No              In_No_sub
AG/2016-17            AG/2016-17

Comment: @user007 Have you checked [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3eed3/9)? It definitely show `AG/2016-17/P/046`.:-(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117404/discussion-between-user007-and-10086).

Comment: @10086 yeah. I checked it.Its perfect.Giving proper output.But in my side, I am using the Phpmyadmin. It is just showing the Partially  output .

Comment: Well, if it's `Phpmyadmin` problem, I also have no idea why it is truncated. :-(

Comment: Just press the  '<-->' expand button

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select MAX(bv) 
from(
    SELECT MAX(CAST(SUBSTRING(In_No, 14, length(In_No)) as UNSIGNED INTEGER)) as bv FROM table_A
    union all
    SELECT MAX(CAST(SUBSTRING(In_No, 14, length(In_No)) as UNSIGNED INTEGER)) as bv FROM table_B
)  as a
```

Comment: i think you didnt give the same name to the two column so when you select max(bv)    the column bv doesn't exist  because your forget as bv in the two selection

Comment: sorry i edited the answer it has a syntax erreur in casting